# What does "RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22" mean?

Tags: linux, wifi, kernel-modules, embedded

I'm trying to build a kernel module to use a **Ralink RT5370** Wi-Fi USB device, with lsusb ID `148f:5370`. My host is a NAS with a Linux kernel based on version 2.6.33.2.

I downloaded the driver sources from the [Mediatek website](https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/rt5370) and I'm pretty much in the same situation described [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-957020-start-0.html); the compiled kernel module `rt5370sta.ko` seems to load correctly because:

```
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # insmod rt5370sta.ko
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # dmesg -c
rtusb init rt2870 --->


=== pAd = f9d70000, size = 511776 ===

<-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
Efuse Size=0x2d [2d0-2fc]
NVM is EFUSE
usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870
```

But the problems start when putting the interface up, in particular the *RTUSBBulkReceive: Submit Rx URB failed -22* message:

```
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # ifconfig ra0 up
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # dmesg -c
RtmpAsicLoadFirmware: ver 21/21, sum cdf7/cdf7, mac cdf72100
NICLoadFirmware: firmware loaded already
<-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db81c4!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db81f0!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db821c!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db8198!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db8114!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9db8140!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d8295c!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d71f90!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d71fc0!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d829f4!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d82904!
RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj f9d829c4!
-->RTUSBVenderReset
<--RTUSBVenderReset
Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
Key2Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
Key3Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
Key4Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
1. Phy Mode = 5
2. Phy Mode = 5
NVM is Efuse and its size =2d[2d0-2fc]
phy mode> Error! The chip does not support 5G band 15!
RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1
3. Phy Mode = 9
AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
NICInitRT5390RFRegisters: Initialize frequency - EEPROM = 46, RF_R17 = 46
AsicSetRxAnt, switch to main antenna
bAutoTxAgcG = 0
---> InitFrequencyCalibration
InitFrequencyCalibration: frequency offset in the EEPROM = 46
<--- InitFrequencyCalibration
MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
RTUSBBulkReceive: Submit Rx URB failed -22
<==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
0x1300 = 00064300
```

Of course it doesn't scan and the **overruns** start to increment:

```
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # /usr/local/bin/iwlist ra0 scan
ra0       No scan results

[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # ifconfig ra0
ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1C:BF:XX:XX:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:1098 frame:1098
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3400 (3.3 KiB)
```

In this situation, checking *dmesg* again leads to a lot of those **-22** errors:

```
[/share/Public/ralink/alt] # dmesg -c
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Submit Rx URB failed(-22), status=0
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22
CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Submit Rx URB failed(-22), status=0
CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Submit Rx URB failed(-22), status=0
```

So my question is: what does *RTUSBBulkOutMLMEPacket: Submit MLME URB failed -22* mean and how to solve it, if possible? I wasn't able to find this info anywhere.

Comment: You can look up Linux `errno`s, and you'll find `-22` (or 22) is `EINVAL` (invalid argument). As to why it fails, the whole message exchange seems to fail, starting with `Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)`. I can only guess the reason for that: wrong version of driver you try to compile, something went wrong during compile and you didn't notice, or the fact that both Realtek firmware and drivers are frequently very bad quality.

Comment: ```Key1Str``` is a value inside the file ```/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat``` which is read by the kernel module and contains the encryption keys, but it shouldn't be "blocking" (and also the guy on the Gentoo linked thread had it). During compile I didn't get errors, only the usual warnings (missing cast, unused variables, ...), so should I throw in the towel?

Comment: Does the Ralink source give any indication with which kernel version it is supposed to work? Can you try with a newer Linux kernel on different hardware if the driver works there (or if possible there's an in-tree driver that works)? If yes, that would narrow down the problem to "Ralink source is meant for particular kernel version".

Comment: Yes, on the README file inside the TAR archive it says "Supporting Kernel: linux kernel 2.4 and 2.6 series", so I should be OK with 2.6.33.2 (and that's the reason I tried with my old NAS with that kernel, which of course can't be updated being embedded). I would like to know what argument is invalid, but I don't know how to troubleshoot.